# graph database in nodejs

Tags: database, node.js

A bit of an abstract question...

I'm looking at graph databases in nodejs.

Of all the options I've been able to find: Neo4J, Infinite Graph, Sones, InfoGrid, etc, none seem to have node APIs, so will have to be accessed through some flavor of HTTP. Does anyone have any experience working with any of these? What would be the best choice?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes,
you might look at https://github.com/thingdom/node-neo4j (example at http://gensen.herokuapp.com/show/34) and https://github.com/neo4j/neo4js for some nice bindings, example at https://github.com/tbaum/heroku-node-neo4js

HTH

Comment: Note that this library has been retired since neo4j 3.0’s NodeJS driver (as noted in the repo link above)

Answer (score 3):

Don't scare off! Node.js is very good at using HTTP and parsing JSON. You don't really need an abstraction over those "low-level" actions. You can actually write your own abstraction package easily and publish it :)

[Neo4J REST API](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api.html) is what you want to use with node. I've heard only positive from my colleague about Neo4j.

I personally have been using CouchDB ( not a graph-db, but still a NoSQL db ) http api with node.js, and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

If you're fancy of keep things simple, try [levelgraph](https://github.com/mcollina/levelgraph). It's a graph db that wraps around LevelDB - a key/value data store

Comment: Here is the author of LevelGraph :D. Cool to see it mentioned here!